# Find a one-dimensional sufficient statistic for theta

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am try to find the one-dimensional sufficient statistic for $\theta$. Although, I'm a bit confused about how you would arrive to the sufficient statistic.

Here is the common density function:

> $f\left(x_{i} ; \theta\right)=\frac{1}{\theta \sqrt{\pi}} e^{\frac{-x_{i}^{2}}{\theta^{2}}}$, $-\infty<x_{i}<\infty, i=1,2, \ldots, n,$ where $\theta>0$ is unknown parameter.

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: How do you find a sufficient statistic in general?

Comment: Since theta is unknown it would be through the factorization theorem.

Comment: Well, nobody has asked you to clarify : then again, nobody understood. If you can add some context to your question i.e. which textbook you are reading from, some definitions and if you've done similar computations for sufficient statistics before, then it will be helpful. Ping me at @TeresaLisbon once you're done. It was kind to ask for clarifications, but unfortunately it is better to provide as much as you can at the starting, it gives you a head start and attracts better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to use the factorization theorem, which says that if $f(x|\theta)=u(x)v[r(x),\theta]$, then r(x) is a sufficient statistic for theta.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\theta\sqrt \pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\theta^2}}$$

Then for a sample,

$$\begin{split}f(x)&=\prod\frac{1}{\theta\sqrt \pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\theta^2}}\\
&=\underbrace{1}_{u(x)}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{\theta^n\pi^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{\theta^2}\sum x^2}}_{=v[r(x),\theta]}\end{split}$$

Hence $\sum x^2$ is sufficient for theta.

Comment: Is this case what would be u(x)?

Comment: u(x)=1. You could have also set $u(x)=\frac 1 {\pi^{n/2}}$ and adjusted $v[r(x),\theta]$ accordingly. It doesn't change the answer. (It's okay if x doesn't actually appear in the expression.)